How to fix that responses through Apache / mod_jk are slow
When requesting an image from my Tomcat web application (size 3 MBs) takes 1.425 ms, but requesting it from Apache, connected via mod_jk, from the same server, takes 2.478 ms, thus 75% slower.
What may cause this? Can I do something to improve the speed here?
No special config, just mod_jk with one worker, default port, ...
Versions:
Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Apache Tomcat/9.0.31 (Ubuntu)
JVM Version: 11.0.25+9-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu120.04
000-default.conf:
<VirtualHost: *:80>
    # ...

    JkMount /kitodo ajp13_worker
    JkMount /kitodo/* ajp13_worker
    <Location /kitodo>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

server.xml:
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
        port="8009"
        redirectPort="8443"
        secretRequired="false" />


The problem was caused by the entry
JkLogLevel trace

in file /etc/apache2/mods-available/jk.conf. (We finally came about it, because the log file flooded the disk ….) Setting this back to JkLogLevel info fixed it for us.

Routing requests for static content via Tomcat has a high capacity cost and still has a performance cost compared with configuring Apache to access the files directly but comes with significant complexity. A compromise solution is to use mod_cache to cache the output of tomcat.
